# FCM token generated but Message not received

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
type here
```

## problem

*I am working on integrating Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) into my Angular application using the modular approach. The FCM token is generated successfully, and Firebase console confirms that messages are sent successfully. However, I'm facing issues with receiving messages on the client side.*

## app.component.ts

```
import { Component, inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Messaging,
  getToken,
  onMessage,
  MessagePayload,
} from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'PushNotes';
  private readonly _messaging = inject(Messaging);
  mesage = Messaging;
  private readonly _message = new BehaviorSubject<unknown | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
      if (permission === 'granted') console.log('Permission granted');
      else if (permission === 'denied') console.log('Permission denied');
    });
    debugger;
    getToken(this._messaging)
      .then((token) => {
        console.log('Token', token);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log('Token error', error));

    onMessage(this._messaging, (payload: MessagePayload) => {
      console.log('Message received', payload);
      this._message.next(payload);
    });
  }
  onClickIcon(): void {
    debugger;

    console.log('Icon clicked!');
    onMessage(this._messaging, (payload: MessagePayload) => {
      console.log('Message received', payload);
      this._message.next(payload);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Token Generation is successful while onMessage Not receive any message.while message is successfully sent from  firebase console.